# IBM Worklight - How do I tell if Worklight Studio is running v6.0.0.0 or v6.0.0.1?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When I navigate to the link to upgrade Worklight studio from the tech note (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574) it sends me to a series of pages and I end up here (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/install.html) which instructs me to use the Eclipse Market place.

I have done this, but I can't see where it states I have actually upgraded to v6.0.0.1 as all the details in Eclipse still indicate 6.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not really clear right now... but if you will navigate in Eclipse to either `Help > About Eclipse` or `Help > Install New Software... > Already Installed` you will see there the full version number, and it will also include the build date. If the build date is very recent, that's v6.0.0.1.

6.0.0.20130926-1933 == Worklight 6.0.0.x(1...) from September 26th 2013 @ 19:33.
[image]

This will be clearer in future releases of IBM Worklight.

Also, here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574
Where it says "Fix Pack 1", that actually refers to v6.0.0.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Marketplace description has been updated to make it easier to identify the fixpack version.

However, you should use the method Idan describes above to verify the specific build. iFixes (Interim Fixes) are smaller fixes that do not update the vx.x.x.x number, but do update the build date. When you update the Worklight Developer Edition, you'll always get the latest build available.

[image]